# For what functions does change of measure preserve integral?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Assume $\nu$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\mu$, both of which are $\sigma$-finite measures on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$. Let $f = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$ be the Radon-Nikodym derivative. I am curious about characterizing the functions $g$ for which the following holds:

$$\int g d\nu = \int g f d\mu $$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Properties) says that this holds for $\nu-$integrable functions (i.e. functions such that $\int|g| d\nu < \infty$. However, I am not sure why this is the case, as I tried to prove this for all measurable $g$:

---

1. For indicator functions:

For $E \in \mathcal{F}$, it follows by definition that, $$\int1_E d\nu = \int_E d\nu = \int_E f d\mu$$

2. For simple functions:

These are just finite linear combinations of indicators, and so this should also follow easily similarly as in (1).

3. For non-negative random variables

For $g$ such a random variable, we may consider the sequence of simple functions $\{ g_n\}$ increasing pointwise to $g$. Then,

$$ \int g d\nu =^1 \lim_n \int g_n d\nu =^2 \lim_n \int g_n f d\mu =^3 \lim_n \int gf d\mu $$
where (1) follows from MCT, (2) follows from step (2), and (3) follows from MCT.

4. For general random variables (Is this where trouble is?)

Let $g = g^+ - g^-$. Then, we may approximate $g_n^+ \rightarrow g^+, g_m^- \rightarrow g^-$, where approximations are simple functions.

Then, $$\int g d\nu = \int g^+ - g^- d\nu =^2 \int g^+ - \int g^- d\nu = ... $$

Where the ... represent the same argument as in step (3).

---

$\textbf{However, I think that equality (2) in the last step is problematic - I suppose that we can only do (2) if $g$ is $\nu-$integrable?}$ But then, we may very well have a set $E \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\nu(E) = \infty$: however, by what we showed in step (1) - we can still use the change of measure formula. So, if we say that this holds for only $\nu$-integrable functions, aren't we excluding indicators of sets with infinite $\nu$-measure where it also holds? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are ignoring existence of the integrals. The equation does not even make sense for all measurable functions $g$ since the integrals may not exist.

Comment: @geetha290krm I see. But what about the indicators of sets with infinite measure?  Can we then not equate the measure of the set to the integral over its indicator function?

Comment: The equality (2) does not make sense if $\int g^+d\nu$ and $\int g^- d\nu$ have value infinity.